# Toggle class on each tr row when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason I can't get the class of "selected" to toggle on when each row is clicked

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g8gumhg0/1/

#### jQuery:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
};
```

#### CSS:

```
table tr.user:hover {
    background: #007A00;
}
table tr.selected {
    background: #198719;
}
```

Should be a simple fix, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

You are missing a closing bracket at the end.